# Microsoft Bot Framework Chain.While example

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to loop a dialog in a number of iterations.

Example: I like to ask a question 5 times in a row (with different parameters). I am able to loop my dialog infinity with `MyDialog.Loop()` - no problem.

But I need a finite number - I figured I need to use `Chain.While()`.

So far no success and I cannot find any examples of using `Chain.While()`.

Any help or sample code is much appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a fixed count while loop:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task SampleChain_While_Count()
    {
        var root =
            Chain
            .PostToChain()
            .Select(_ => (IReadOnlyList<string>)Array.Empty<string>())
            .While
            (
                items => Chain
                            .Return(items)
                            .Select(i => i.Count < 3),
                items => Chain
                            .Return(items)
                            .Select(i => $"question {i.Count}")
                            .PostToUser()
                            .WaitToBot()
                            .Select(a => items.Concat(new[] { a.Text }).ToArray())
            )
            .Select(items => string.Join(",", items))
            .PostToUser();

        using (var container = Build(Options.ResolveDialogFromContainer | Options.Reflection))
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder
                .RegisterInstance(root)
                .As<IDialog<object>>();
            builder.Update(container);

            await AssertScriptAsync(container,
                "hello",
                "question 0",
                "A",
                "question 1",
                "B",
                "question 2",
                "C",
                "A,B,C"
                );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample showing an Email chain, using the While to ask for the emails recipients:

```
Func<string, IDialog<string>> Ask = toUser =>
    Chain.Return(toUser)
    .PostToUser()
    .WaitToBot()
    .Select(m => m.Text);

IDialog<IReadOnlyList<string>> recipientsDialog =
    Chain
    .Return(Array.Empty<string>())
    .While(items => Ask($"have {items.Length} recipients, want more?").Select(text => text == "yes"),
    items => Ask("next recipient?").Select(item => items.Concat(new[] { item }).ToArray()));

var emailDialog = from hello in Chain.PostToChain().Select(m => m.Text + " back!").PostToUser()
                    from subject in Ask("what is the subject?")
                    from body in Ask("what is the body?")
                    from recipients in recipientsDialog
                    select new { subject, body, recipients };

var rootDialog = emailDialog
    .Select(email => $"'{email.subject}': '{email.body}' to {email.recipients.Count} recipients")
    .PostToUser();
```

Comment: This makes sense when the user input(s) collected to determine whether to continue the loop or not.What I like to do (and need help with) is how to modify this code to behave like the simple While (i=-;i<5;i++) loop. No need for dialog prompting the user. 

The concept is MyDialog.While( start from 0, go till 5, increment by 1).

Thank you for your help